# Mapping listView items with photos from the cloud

Tags: android, listview, imgur

I have some places in a `listView`. These are picked from a `Google Map`, for which I would like to take a picture. One for each. These photos should be available online, so I have searched for some proper solutions. I've choosed imgur's API.
Is it possible to link pictures with places? I would like to make mapping between uploaded pictures and `listView` items.

Photo picker and uploader class:

```
public class OAuthTestActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE = 1001;

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID";

    private LinearLayout rootView;

    private String accessToken;
    private String refreshToken;

    private String picturePath = "";
    private Button send;

    private String uploadedImageUrl = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
        rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
        rootView.addView(tv);
        setContentView(rootView);

        String action = getIntent().getAction();

        if (action == null || !action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) { // We need access token to use Imgur's api

            tv.setText("Start OAuth Authorization");

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(AUTHORIZATION_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
                    .appendQueryParameter("response_type", "token")
                    .appendQueryParameter("state", "init")
                    .build();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setData(uri);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } else { // Now we have the token, can do the upload

            tv.setText("Got Access Token");

            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            Log.d("Got imgur's access token", uri.toString());
            String uriString = uri.toString();
            String paramsString = "http://callback?" + uriString.substring(uriString.indexOf("#") + 1);
            Log.d("tag", paramsString);
            List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(URI.create(paramsString), "utf-8");
            Log.d("tag", Arrays.toString(params.toArray(new NameValuePair[0])));

            for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
                if (pair.getName().equals("access_token")) {
                    accessToken = pair.getValue();
                } else if (pair.getName().equals("refresh_token")) {
                    refreshToken = pair.getValue();
                }
            }

            Log.d("tag", "access_token = " + accessToken);
            Log.d("tag", "refresh_token = " + refreshToken);

            Button chooseImage = new Button(this);
            rootView.addView(chooseImage);
            chooseImage.setText("Choose an image");
            chooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
                }
            });

            send = new Button(this);
            rootView.addView(send);
            send.setText("send to imgur");
            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (picturePath != null && picturePath.length() > 0 &&
                            accessToken != null && accessToken.length() > 0) {
                        (new UploadToImgurTask()).execute(picturePath);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (send == null) return;
        if (picturePath == null || picturePath.length() == 0) {
            send.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("tag", "request code : " + requestCode + ", result code : " + resultCode);
        if (data == null) {
            Log.d("tag" , "data is null");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.d("tag", "image path : " + picturePath);
            cursor.close();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    // Here is the upload task
    class UploadToImgurTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            final String upload_to = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(upload_to);

            try {
                HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                        .addPart("image", new FileBody(new File(params[0])))
                        .build();

                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);

                final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                        localContext);

                final String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response
                        .getEntity());

                final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response_string);

                Log.d("tag", json.toString());

                JSONObject data = json.optJSONObject("data");
                uploadedImageUrl = data.optString("link");
                Log.d("tag", "uploaded image url : " + uploadedImageUrl);

                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            if (aBoolean.booleanValue()) { // after sucessful uploading, show the image in web browser
                Button openBrowser = new Button(OAuthTestActivity.this);
                rootView.addView(openBrowser);
                openBrowser.setText("Open Browser");
                openBrowser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uploadedImageUrl));
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

}
```